# convert long long into string

Tags: iphone, ios

What is long long type ? It's an integer which takes 8 bytes , am I right? I want to convert long long type into NSString as follows.

```
long long fbid = [[friend objectForKey:@"id"]longLongValue];
```

I want value of `fbid` in my `NSString *str` variable. What can I do?

Comment: firstly you have convert it in C string...
then use the function stroll() which is define in < stdlib.h >

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", fbid];
```

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you would like to keep this file with you as a reference, I made it as an image to appear nice:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to raise this answer so that other readers can know that this answer is useful when they come and read this post.

Comment: You can use the `<pre>` formatting here on SO to make text appear the way you inputted, FYI.

Answer (score 4):

```
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%qi",fbid];
```

Comment: %i is for int values, not long long values.

Comment: You are correct.  According to [link](http://www.makebetterthings.com/objective-c/nsstring-format-specifiers/) it should be "%qi"

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str =[[NSNumber numberWithLong:fbid] stringValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code would return you number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970.

```
- (NSString *) timeInMiliSeconds
    {

        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];               //   Current Date
        NSString * timeInMiliseconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", [@(floor([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)) longLongValue]];    //   Returns you number of milliseconf
        return timeInMiliseconds;
    }
```

For seconds: `[@(floor([date timeIntervalSince1970]))]`

Comment: Code only answers are usually [frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2596334). Try adding an [explination or code comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269981/2596334). Thanks.